# Simpy - How do I start a clock that keeps track of work shifts and days in the background?

Tags: python, simpy

Hi I am new to using Simpy.

I have a simulation for workers that work various shifts and I want to keep track of which shift is happening right now and also which day it is based off of `env.now` but I am having trouble with this.

I want my simulation to run but I'd like some form of a clock that prints out if a shift has ended or if a day has ended and such.

```
def do_task(env):
    yield env.timeout(30) # each task takes 30 minutes to complete
    print("Completed task")

def start(env):
    while True:
        # at the end of 24 hours (24 * 60)...
        if env.now != 0 and env.now % 1440 == 0:
            print("Day is done")
        # shift is 4 hours (4 * 60)..
        elif env.now != 0 and env.now % 240 == 0:
            print("Shift is done")

        yield env.process(do_task(env)) # I want this to be running with the above print statements printing stuff at the right times.


env = simpy.Environment()
env.process(start(env))
env.run(until = 7200) # 3 days (3 * 24 * 60 minutes)
```

The code above, of course, does not work.  The statement `env.now % 1440 == 0` doesn't quite work because if the timeout process isn't factored perfectly into 1440, it's not going to print that the day is done.  How do I achieve the behavior I want?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is too simple but this worked for me.

```
def ShiftClock(env):
shift=1
while True:
    if env.now % 8*3600 == 0:
        shift+=1
        if shift>3:shift=1
    print(shift)
env=simpy.Environment()
TimeClock=env.process(ShiftClock(env))
env.run(until=7*24*3600)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you're overcomplicating this. What you need is a simple process that does a timeout to 1440:

```
def day_timer(env):
    while True:
        yield env.timeout(1440)
        print(print("Day is done"))
```

Your code will become more complex if you want to actually interrupt current processes at the end of your day or the end of the shift. Say it gets to the end of the day and you want your workers to stop their work and go home (even if in the middle of a job). In this case then refer to the [machine shop example](https://simpy.readthedocs.io/en/3.0/examples/machine_shop.html), where a process gets interrupted:

```
class Machine(object):
    """A machine produces parts and my get broken every now and then.

    If it breaks, it requests a *repairman* and continues the production
    after the it is repaired.

    A machine has a *name* and a numberof *parts_made* thus far.

    """
    def __init__(self, env, name, repairman):
        self.env = env
        self.name = name
        self.parts_made = 0
        self.broken = False

        # Start "working" and "break_machine" processes for this machine.
        self.process = env.process(self.working(repairman))
        env.process(self.break_machine())

    def working(self, repairman):
        """Produce parts as long as the simulation runs.

        While making a part, the machine may break multiple times.
        Request a repairman when this happens.

        """
        while True:
            # Start making a new part
            done_in = time_per_part()
            while done_in:
                try:
                    # Working on the part
                    start = self.env.now
                    yield self.env.timeout(done_in)
                    done_in = 0  # Set to 0 to exit while loop.

                except simpy.Interrupt:
                    self.broken = True
                    done_in -= self.env.now - start  # How much time left?

                    # Request a repairman. This will preempt its "other_job".
                    with repairman.request(priority=1) as req:
                        yield req
                        yield self.env.timeout(REPAIR_TIME)

                    self.broken = False

            # Part is done.
            self.parts_made += 1

    def break_machine(self):
        """Break the machine every now and then."""
        while True:
            yield self.env.timeout(time_to_failure())
            if not self.broken:
                # Only break the machine if it is currently working.
                self.process.interrupt()
```